# App to support all i-Phone screen resolutions?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, retina

I create an app in which I show all the `UIControls`. My app is running on Retina 4.0, which code should I use to make my app for all screen resolutions?

In my app I uses OOPS concept to store my data. I created a class `User` and made property for username, DOB his pic in objects and created an array in view controller which held these objects. In detail view controller I create a property of `User` class type and show the all info in detail view controller.

When I use the search bar in my view controller to search the user then app is terminated. I used this code:

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    Users *use = [UserList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = use.tableData;
}
```

How can I use my search bar controller in my app?
And how can I make my app run on all screen resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `xib` for `UITableView` then You can set spring and struts from xib if you are not using `xib` then check the Screen size and adjust the from for your `UITableView`